# spring boot batch with MySQL DB always generating primary key as 0

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I am using Spring boot batch (spring-boot-starter-parent version 2.0.2) with MySQL DB.  Earlier I used with Spring boot batch (version 1.5.x) with same MySQL DB and it worked fine.

Right now I can see everytime application it generates primary key as 0 for all metadata tables such as: [image] and it fails because MYSQL throws error "com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'"

Please help in suggesting with it is not auto increment the PRIMARY KEY.

If I create new MySQL database, then application is unable to create tables, no matter which [option](https://gist.github.com/karmanov/499e0dfdf8e5ce119ad4) I chose for spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto. 
My application.properties is below
[image]

And pom.xml as:
[image]

Below is the image of how we are doing job : selecting data from one table and inserting into another table
[image]
Many Thanks

Comment: Can you post how you domain looks like.

Comment: @abdul Sorry, I did not understood what is domain.  We have three jobs and of the job is messageUsage which picks data from one table and does some processing and populates another table.  I have added image of how we are doing.

Answer (score 0):

By using the older version of spring boot I am able to resolve the issue.  Below is the entry in pom that works:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Comment: I was also facing same issue, ID generating as 0, not sure about exact reason, but adding initial entry in BATCH_JOB_SEQ as 1 resolve my issue, from their code stating to generate from 2,3,4,5....